# Any issue with using 14/3 wire for two differrent lights switches?

Tags: lighting, switch

I want to wire two different kitchen lights on two different switches using 14/3.  Black hot for pendant lighting and red hot for recessed lighting.  Grounds and neutrals will be connected all together in a j box.  All on same breaker.  Or is it better to run two 14/2 wires for each light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Running the 14/3 is the easiest way from the switch box to the first light junction box. From that junction box to the junction box for the other set of lights you'd only need 14/2. If the junction boxes for the two different types of lights are far apart, then two 14/2 cables would be the way to go. Either way is good so use the wire you have.

Comment: Do the colors of a wire need to be changed to do this?

Comment: @Orbit  Nope. If running 14/3, both the black and red wires will be switched hots.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm from Europe, so I thought the 3 poles would be Ground, neutral and hot.

Comment: @Orbit AFAIK the use of the "/2" and "/3", along with the indication of Black and Red for hots is a _very_ strong indicator for North America and the US in particular. UK would use "twin-core" for our "/2", I'm not sure what they'd use for a "/3" or what the EU would call those.

Comment: @Freeman: I think I'm still a bit confused by the names. So /2 means 2 poles excl ground? In Europe we use the names 3 pole and 5 pole, this includes ground though. 3 pole has ground, neutral and phase, 5 pole has this too, plus 2 switched hot. Probably 4 pole exists too, but I've never seen a building supply store who sells it.

Comment: @Orbit, yes, the "/2" sounds like your "3 pole" - Generally, we'd call it hot (or line or phase), neutral and ground.  A "/3" cable is pretty common here, but a "/4" is somewhat rare (at least in my non-pro experience). Basically, we don't count the ground wire because a while back (1960's?) we didn't run ground wires, so when grounding became required, we stuck with the counting format and it was "just understood" that the ground wire was included but not counted. _That's **my** version of the backstory and I'm sticking with it._

Comment: @FreeMan: That makes sense. It also seems that the ground wire it not always insulated in the US. In Europe the ground wire is always the same as the rest, so it seems more logical to count it too.

Comment: @freeman actually if you look x2 with ground or x3 with ground is how cables are ordered, cordage is usually by the total number of conductors so a 120 cord with a ground would be x3 with the corresponding type like soow. I don’t know why the difference but it only matters on residential as that’s about the only place we use NMB cables.